# Google Analytics - Comparing transactions vs page metrics

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, conversions, page-views, metrics

Is it possible to compare ecommerce transactions (eg product performance) vs page metrics, like average amount of time on page, page views, pages per session, etc? I'm trying to find out things like how many pages visitors browsed before buying something on average. Extending to that, is it possible to find out the # of pages visitors browsed that contains a certain URL? I'm not sure if filters are able to filter the "# of pages" metric by URL? For example, how many pages related to gift catalogue (URL contains www.giftcatalogue.com/ for example) users browsed.

I tried to add a custom report by using product performance as the dimension, and those mentioned as metrics, but it shows 0 for the data (no data for this view). I don't have any filters/segments active, and the date is set to over one year, so that can't be right. Does GA not allow combining ecommerce dimensions with non-ecommerce metrics?